# Why do I need to await a knex.transaction() to begin a transaction in knex

Tags: transactions, knex.js

Why do I need to `await` a `knex.transaction()` to begin a transaction. Calling `const trx = knex.transaction()` should be sufficient. I don't need to tell the database I am starting a transaction until I actually want to read or write data.

e.g., if all I am doing is atomically writing data like

```
trx('myTable1').insert(data1)
trx('myTable2').insert(data2)
await trx.commit
```

Under the hood I am trying to create a sql query like

```
BEGIN
INSERT "myTable1" VALES(...)
INSERT "myTable2" VALES(...)
COMMIT
```

the `const trx = knex.transaction()` should create BEGIN
and the `await trx.commit` should be adding COMMIT, serializing this over the write to the database and awaiting acceptance or rejection from the DB. In my example above, the only the `await` required should be for the `trx.commit()`

Thanks